# What was your worst bike accident, and how could it have been prevented?

Tags: safety, accidents

**How can we improve our safety?**

We can lean from past accidents or near-accidents. Most of us are able to share relevant experiences. Could the incidents have been avoided, in hindsight? What can we learn from them?

Comment: Not sure whether the question is too subjective. In a way, the sum of the subjective experiences is our objective reality. Such a resource does not seem to exist on bicycles SE or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I recently switched to a new bike and got a little too confident after getting a PR on a trail and decided I could rider even faster. I ended up casing a jump on a familiar trail, laying my bike down nearly hitting a tree and scratching up my helmet (luckily I was wearing my full face, otherwise I would have had a had a torn open cheek). I tore through a jacket and a jersey and have a scar on my elbow now.

What were my errors? How could I have prevented this?

I hadn't dialed in my suspension yet. The rebound was set too low, so I didn't get the boost I expected. I would normally clear the particular jump at even a slow speed and came no where close despite riding faster than usual. It was only my second ride on the new bike and it was absurd for me to assume I had it dialed in.

Other preventable errors:

Coming up a long climb and going into a descent with cold brakes not giving that any thought. I came into the first corner with cold brakes. Had I dragged my brakes a bit on the descent they would have warmed up.

Day dreaming on a familiar trail. I let myself get distracted because I "know the trail" and ended up over the bars. It was flat elevation but a bit technical. I should have been focusing on the trail.

Most of my tire burping experiences have been due to not enough tire pressure. I rarely check pressure before a ride. If it feels ok on the up I (wrongly) assume it's set up for the down.

Forgetting to turn my clutch back on after removing a wheel (Shimano derailleur). I ended up with my chain jumping a few times before I caught it. In my defense I was used to SRAM derailleurs.

Another setup issue: I changed SPD cleats and didn't adjust the release on my pedals (forgetting I tightened them to deal with the aging cleats). I missed clipping out on a climb due to it being way more difficult than my muscle memory remembered. I hadn't fallen due to not being able to unclip in years.

A lot of errors can be prevented by just doing due diligence on your bike set up and maintenance. I am definitely not as diligent as I should be.